# Where can I find a list of WM.Call_Menu names?

Tags: shortcut

I'm trying to create shortcuts so I can hotkey the various menus in Blender.  But I can't find the "name" of the menu I want.

[image]
.

I'm trying to do the same thing, but for the 2D view window.  Right clicking the menu didn't give me any info, and a web search didn't turn up anything either.

Where can I find a list of all available wm.call_menu names, so I can do this with other menus?